# Having trouble lining up cards

Tags: html, css

I'm a newbie to HTML and I've been attempting to create a website for my friend and in the site I am making cards to display information. Since I am making multiple cards for multiple sections I wanted to line up all the cards in their different sections but I have been having trouble doing so.

First, I tried inline-block, since I guessed all of the elements added up would be a block but as a result nothing happened. Next and lastly I had tried creating a table and listing the cards in the table but that also didn't work too. It partly did, but the other cards were shrunken down and the text was hanging out. How can I fix it?

```css
* {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}

nav {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-flex;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: #fafafa;
  padding: 40px;
}

a:hover {
  float: right;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.Fcard1 {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 16%;
  margin-left: 32px;
}

.Fcard1:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.FCcontainer1 {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}

.Fcard2 {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
  width: 16%;
  margin-left: 32px;
}

.Fcard2:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.FCcontainer2 {
  padding: 2px 16px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
  <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="/Home/Home.css" -->
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <h2>Shoppables</h2>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Catalog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        <li></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="/Home/Home-Images/search_FILL0_wght400_GRAD0_opsz24.png"></a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#"><img src="/Home/Home-Images/shopping_cart_FILL0_wght400_GRAD0_opsz24.png"></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main>
    <table style="width: 100%;">
      <tr>
        <section class="Featured-Sect">
          <h2 class="Featured-Header" style="margin: 32px;">Featured Products:</h2>

          <td style="width: 100%;">
            <div class="Fcard1">
              <img src="/Home/Home-Images/Placeholder128.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
              <div class="FCcontainer1">
                <h2><b>Placeholder</b></h2>
                <p>$0.00 USD</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>

          <td style="width: 100%;">
            <div class="Fcard1">
              <img src="/Home/Home-Images/Placeholder128.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:100%">
              <div class="FCcontainer1">
                <h2><b>Placeholder</b></h2>
                <p>$0.00 USD</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </td>
      </tr>

      </section>

      </section>
    </table>
  </main>
</body>
```

Comment: You should run your markup through a validator or use a good editor. It has problems. A section element isn't a valid child of a table or table row, for example, and you have improperly nested tags. Also, don't use inline styles. Use a custom class instead. It's much more maintainable and clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting them inside a div class="input-group":

```
<div class="input-group">
  <td style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="Fcard1">
      <img src="/Home/Home-Images/Placeholder128.png" alt="Avatar"
           style="width:100%">
      <div class="FCcontainer1">
        <h2><b>Placeholder</b></h2>
        <p>$0.00 USD</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td>

  <td style="width: 100%;">
    <div class="Fcard1">
      <img src="/Home/Home-Images/Placeholder128.png" alt="Avatar"
           style="width:100%">
      <div class="FCcontainer1">
        <h2><b>Placeholder</b></h2>
        <p>$0.00 USD</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </td></div>
```